# MVC dropdownlist - bind multiple property from items

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have Institutes collection. it contains ID, Description, Name, Age etc properties. I can get ID and Description after selection. but how to get other properties (e.g. Name) based on selection. here, I need "Name" property as well.

I have below onchange function written in javascript . I have to get "Name" property value. I dont want to call server logic again -

```
$("#InstituteID").change(function() {
// Need some logic to get Name value

});
```

Dropdownlist code -

```
@Html.DropDownList("InstituteID",
                       new SelectList(
                           ViewBag.Institutes,
                           "ID",
                           "Description"
                       ),
                "-- Institute Type --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the data-attributes property of select tag options.

You have to modify HTML markup like this:

```
@{
 var Institutes = new List<Institutes>() {
 new Institutes(){ ID=1,Description="test1",Name="name1",age=20 },
 new Institutes(){ ID=2,Description="test2",Name="name2",age=21 },
 new Institutes(){ ID=3,Description="test3",Name="name3",age=22 }
 };
}

<select name="InstituteID" id="InstituteID">
@foreach (var item in Institutes)
{
    <option data-name="@item.Name" data-age="@item.age" value="@item.ID">@item.Description</option>
}
</select>
```

Javascript will look like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#InstituteID").change(function () {
        var element = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var name = element.attr("data-name");
        var name = element.attr("data-age");
        console.log("selected name is:"+ name);
    });
})
```